# django alter css style width on progress bar

Tags: python, css, django

I have a progress bar, with style width set in css, is there a way to update that style width with some logic in django, and how?

```
<div class="progress-bar bg-warning" role="progressbar" style="width: 25%" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
```

Now lets say that i want a more dynamic update on the width?

Comment: Just send the width via context to your view and use double curly brackets  to set the width dynamically. If this is not what you want, let us now and adapt your question.

Comment: Could you explain more please, maybe show an example?

Comment: Please clarify your question. You can send a progress value to your template using context variable (e.g. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) But if you need to be updated after rendering for the first time, then you will probably add some AJAX calls to your backend polling for new progress value and update the template accordingly.

Comment: I asked how to somehow manipulate CSS tag, it is a style tag for CSS and my question was how to manipulate it. Cannot just use normal double bracket and add a value.

Comment: Sure you can. It's part of the template and that's why the double curly brackets are handled by the template engine. Just do `...tyle="width: {{ progress }}%" aria-value...`.